# array_key_exist on first layer of multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

Can somebody tell my why the following code doesn't work?

```
$ReturnData=array(
    'cardauth'=>array('success'=>'')
);

$Query="SELECT cardauth FROM y WHERE x = '".$x."'";
$Data=mysql_query($Query);
while($Row = mysql_fetch_array($Data)){
    foreach($Row as $k => $v){
        if(array_key_exists($k,$ReturnData)){
            $ReturnData[$k]['success']=$v;
        }
    }
}
die(print_r($ReturnData));
```

I'm trying to set the values of the second dimension of the array `$ReturnData` with the column that is being crossed by the mysql fetch.  'cardauth' will be a BIT.  I use the same method to populate single dimension arrays inside of the same loop.  I've removed all the unnecessary code.

`array_key_exists` is not working. `$ReturnData['cardauth']['success']` is not being set to the value of the column.

Comment: The problem was the BIT datatype.  My logic was looking for a 1 or a 0.

Comment: i think the code is fine you need to check the variable $x value or  debug the code, try to print the array out of the loop.

Comment: "array_key_exists is not working" and "Can somebody tell my why the following code doesn't work?" = Needs Debugging Details

Answer (score 0):

Use `else` to solve your problem! This `else` could be:

```
} else  {
  printf("array_key_exists did return true because [%s] does not contain %s",
    implode(array_keys($ReturnData), ', '), 
    $k);
}
```

Comment: `echo sprintf()` is an "antipattern". There is absolutely no reason that anyone should ever write `echo sprintf()` in any code for any reason -- it should be `printf()` every time.